# Immutables @Value.Immutable public final fields (instead of getters)

Tags: java, immutables-library

I code in Kotlin mostly, but I also work on a project written in Java

I would like to use the Immutables library to avoid writing boilerplate code

I'm used to accessing my data class fields without any getters (e.g. `config.value` instead of `config.getValue()`)

I cannot figure out how to do that with the immutables library. It keeps making private final fields

Is there a way to enable generating public final fields?

Comment: Can you provide a small code snippet? It'll make it easier for others to answer your question.

Comment: I'm not sure it's possible to make Immutables work on public, final fields instead of getter-methods, but you can at least remove the `get`-prefix from these methods through configuration: http://immutables.github.io/style.html